# Can you programmatically generate a link to open a Word document and navigate to a particular location within it (preferably a comment)?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-word, office365, openxml-sdk

Can you programmatically generate a link to open a Word document and navigate to a particular location within it (preferably a comment)? Eseentially I want to reproduce the "Create link" feature that is available on comments in the UI, and use a hyperlink.

I have inspected the link that is created by "Create link" and it contains a parameter like this: `nav=eyJjIjo2OTk2Njg1ODd9`. I inspected the OpenXML in the Word document and the value isn't in it.

I've also tried using bookmarks including their name as an anchor in the url, but that did not work.